# How to refer to the variable in adapter apart from RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, variables, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends ListAdapter<Cars, RecyclerAdapter.RecHolder>{
        public TextView name_product1;
        public TextView category_product1;

  class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name_product;
        public TextView category_product;

     public RecHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Recycler_Adapters_items listener) {
          name_Product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.field1);
          category_Product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.field2);
     }
   }
}
```

Then:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.name_product.setText(currentItem.getname_product());
     holder.category_product.setText(currentItem.getcategory_product());
}
```

Later in other method **in adapter** but apart from `class RecyclerHolder` I need to call:

```
name_product.setTextSize();
category_product.setTextSize();
```

The problem is that:
`name_product` and `category_product` are not visible in those methods.
If I initialize it only in adapter (without `RecyclerHolder` then I can't call:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.name_product.setText(currentItem.getname_product());
     holder.category_product.setText(currentItem.getcategory_product());
}
```

Beacuse variables are not visible.
The simple but "weak" solution is to do it like this:

```
 public RecHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Recycler_Adapters_items listener) {
          nameProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.field1);
          category_Product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.field2);
          name_product1 = name_product;
          category_product1 = category_product;
     }
```

But it doesn't satisfy me.
How can I see the same variables in both methods in `Adapter` and class `RecyclerHolder`?

Answer (score 0):

from where are you calling that method which executes

```
name_product.setTextSize();
category_product.setTextSize();
```

one solution is while calling the method pass the view as parameter

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this... I wanted to do it with "this" keyword, but compiler tells that: "Variable is already assigned to this value ".